# Hay un equivalente en bash de goto de cmd?

Tags: cmd, shell

Ejemplo quiero hacer digamos un equivalente de este pero en bash (Obvio en inglés):

```
:inicio
comando1
si "comando"=="comando" ( GOTO inicio
) si no ( GOTO reintentar)
```

Quiero saber que alternativas en bash para convertir un script que tengo en github para convertirlo a bash para abarcar publico (Si tuviera siquiera). Aquí el link de [Github](https://github.com/alejandro-alzate/MinecraftServerLoader)

Comment: Qué tiene que ver esto con Java??

Comment: como tal no existe `goto` pero bash maneja el concepto de funciones por lo que solo seria llamar a al funcion... que en terminos simples es el equivalete a `ve a`

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es: **No**.

Tendrás que utilizar `break` o `continue` o alguna que otra solución un poco más elaborada como las que se proponen en esta otra [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-bash).

Comment: Meh la funciones me sirven y para el que se preguntaba el de lo de java Es que voy a hacer unas cosillas con en default-jre